# Rust: Joining and iterating over futures' results

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have some code that iterates over objects and uses an async method on each of them sequentially before doing something with the results. I'd like to change it so that the async method calls are joined into a single future before being executed. The important bit below is in `HolderStruct::add_squares`. My current code looks like this:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;

struct AsyncMethodStruct {
    value: u64
}

impl AsyncMethodStruct {
    fn new(value: u64) -> Self {
        AsyncMethodStruct {
            value
        }
    }
    async fn get_square(&self) -> Result<u64> {
        Ok(self.value * self.value)
    }
}

struct HolderStruct {
    async_structs: Vec<AsyncMethodStruct>
}

impl HolderStruct {
    fn new(async_structs: Vec<AsyncMethodStruct>) -> Self {
        HolderStruct {
            async_structs
        }
    }
    async fn add_squares(&self) -> Result<u64> {
        let mut squares = Vec::with_capacity(self.async_structs.len());
        for async_struct in self.async_structs.iter() {
            squares.push(async_struct.get_square().await?);
        }
        let mut sum = 0;
        for square in squares.iter() {
            sum += square;
        }

        return Ok(sum);
    }
}
```

I'd like to change `HolderStruct::add_squares` to something like this:

```rust
use futures::future::join_all;
// [...]
impl HolderStruct {
    async fn add_squares(&self) -> Result<u64> {
        let mut square_futures = Vec::with_capacity(self.async_structs.len());
        for async_struct in self.async_structs.iter() {
            square_futures.push(async_struct.get_square());
        }
        let square_results = join_all(square_futures).await;
        let mut sum = 0;
        for square_result in square_results.iter() {
            sum += square_result?;
        }

        return Ok(sum);
    }
}
```

However, the compiler gives me this error using the above:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`
  --> src/main.rs:46:20
   |
46 |             sum += square_result?;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&std::result::Result<u64, anyhow::Error>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `&std::result::Result<u64, anyhow::Error>`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::into_result`
```

How would I change the code to not have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
for square_result in square_results.iter()
```

Lose the `iter()` call here.

```rust
for square_result in square_results
```

You seem to be under impression that calling `iter()` is mandatory to iterate over a collection. Actually, anything that implements [IntoIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) can be used in a for loop.

Calling [iter()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) on a `Vec<T>` derefs to slice (`&[T]`) and yields an iterator over *references* to the vectors elements. The `?` operator tries to take the value out of the `Result`, but that is only possible if you own the `Result` rather than just have a reference to it.

However, if you simply use a vector itself in a for statement, it will use the [IntoIterator implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-1) for `Vec<T>` which will yield items of type `T` rather than `&T`.

`square_results.into_iter()` does the same thing, albeit more verbosely. It is mostly useful when using iterators in a functional style, a la `vector.into_iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect()`.